# How to get the file from the folder based on date

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have multiple file in a folder with a naming convention

```
Name_MoreName_DDMMYYYY_SomeNumber_HHMMSS.txt
```

How can I get the file which has oldest Date and Time (i.e. oldest DDMMYYYY and HHMMSS).

Ex:

- Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072334.txt
- Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072134.txt
- Name_MoreName_24012012_SomeNumber_072339.txt
- Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072135.txt

So the oldest file will be

```
Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072134.txt
```

how can i take the oldest file only ?

**Edit** 
This is what I have done so far.. in a forach loop I am reading file name one by one

```
private void FileInformation(string fileName, ref string concatFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string completeFileName = fileName.Trim();
                string[] fileComponenets = completeFileName.Split('_');

                string fileDate = string.Empty;
                string fileTime = string.Empty;


                if (fileComponenets.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileDate = fileComponenets[4].Replace(".txt", "").Trim();
                    fileTime = fileComponenets[2].ToString();
                    concatFile = fileDate + "-" + fileTime;
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                            }

        }
```

-- Main function

```
string fileStats = string.Empty;
 foreach (string filePath in arrFileCollection)
                {
                    if (filePath.ToLower().Contains("Name_MoreName_")&&
                        filePath.ToLower().Contains(".txt"))
                    {
                                                string concatFile = string.Empty;
                        FileInformation(filePath.Replace(dirPath, ""), ref concatFile);
                        fileStats = fileStats + "," + concatFile;
                    }
}
```

Now I am getting all date time in a string with comma seperated value. Now I am stuck up. How can I take the smallest among them and get the related file

**EDIT2**

Note: Framework is .NET 2.0

Comment: is the file name predefined and guaranteed to be in same format?

Comment: @Adil Yes, it is a predefined format

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite : I have updated solution/code as per .NET framework 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string oldestFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                             .OrderBy(file => ExtractDateTimeFrom(file))
                             .First(); // FirstOrDefault
```

And write method which will parse your file name and extract date from it:

```
public static DateTime ExtractDateTimeFrom(string fileName)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@".+_(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)_.+_(\d\d\d\d\d\d).txt");
    var match = regex.Match(fileName);
    string dateString = match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value;
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyyHHmmsss", null);
}
```

**.NET 2.0** Simplest solution:

```
string oldestFile = "";
DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.Max;

foreach(string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    DateTime date = ExtractDateTimeFrom(fileName);
    if (date < oldestDate)
    {
        oldestFile = fileName;
        oldestDate = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the date and time from the file and I also able to concatinate them in one string with comma seperation.

Comment: :( I believe that this is for 3.5+ framework but I am working on .NET2.0

Answer (score 1):

Use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo classes. For example, just to give idea:

```
        IOrderedEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInfo =  new DirectoryInfo("D:\\")
                                                      .EnumerateFiles()
                                                      .OrderBy(f=>f.FullName);
```

UPDATE: For .NET 2.0, I would suggest you to separate the comparison logic from your main code... so why not create a custom type implementing IComparable interface.

```
public class CustomFileInfo :IComparable<CustomFileInfo>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MoreName { get; set; }
    public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime FileTime { get; set; }

    public CustomFileInfo(string fileNameString)
    {
        string[] fileNameStringSplited = fileNameString.Split('_');
        this.Name = fileNameStringSplited[0];
        this.MoreName = fileNameStringSplited[1];
        this.FileDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fileNameStringSplited[2], "ddMMyyyy", null);
        this.Number = int.Parse(fileNameStringSplited[3]);
        this.FileTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fileNameStringSplited[4], "HHmmss", null);
    }

    public int CompareTo(CustomFileInfo other)
    {
        // add more comparison criteria here
        if (this.FileDate == other.FileDate) 
            return 0;
        if (this.FileDate > other.FileDate)
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then in your code, you may simple get files using DirectoryInfo and compare each files...

```
    FileInfo[] filesInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\").GetFiles();
    //set first file initially as minimum
    CustomFileInfo oldestFileInfo = new CustomFileInfo(filesInfo[0].FullName);

    for (int i = 1; i < filesInfo.Length; i++)
    {
            CustomFileInfo currentFileInfo = new CustomFileInfo(filesInfo[i].FullName);
        //compare each file and keep the oldest file reference in oldestFileInfo
            if (oldestFileInfo.CompareTo(currentFileInfo) < 0)
                oldestFileInfo = currentFileInfo;
    }
```

You may optimize code for use and customize the comparison code as per your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

**Updated**

```
List<string> address = new List<string>() { "Name_MoreName_22012011_SomeNumber_072334.txt",
            "Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072134.txt",
            "Name_MoreName_24012012_SomeNumber_072339.txt",
            "Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072135.txt",};
            DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
            dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";
            address = address.OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDateTime((s.Split('_')[2]).Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-"), dtfi)).ToList();
            string oldest = address[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe?

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
        Regex rex          = new Regex(@"^.*_(\d+)\.txt");
        int date           = int.MaxValue;
        int oldestdate     = int.MaxValue;
        String oldestfile;
        foreach(String filePath in filePaths)
        {
            Match match = rex.Match(filePath);

            if(match.Success)
                date = int.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value);
            if (date < oldestdate)
            {
                oldestdate = date;
                oldestfile = filePath;
            }
        }
```